# How to crawl RSS feeds periodically from websites using python

Tags: android, python, machine-learning, rss

I want make a news aggregator `android` app using my laptop as local server for My project.I have plan to use apache, php, mysql on my backend.I decided to apply simple machine learning technique to this application.So this app is not only able to collect articles but also classify them by their topic.

I have already implemented basic `Scikit-learn` `Naive Bayes classifier`.
I want to know how to automatically crawl and store `RSS` feeds from multiple sites on a server over a certain period of time.What kind of library or technique should i use to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the more common and used libraries available on Python for this task and run your script using Cron or Windows Task Scheduler (according to the OS you will use).

Using a common library will allow you to easily get support, read great documentation or find many pages when search for errors / tutorials online.

The libraries I'd use for general scraping and RSS are:

- [Urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) (to get internet pages)
- [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (for pulling data out of HTML and XML files)
- [FeedParser](https://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries) (to handle RSS feeds)

Here's a simple and minimal example that pulls current Ethereum value scraping a website using BeautifulSoup:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
page = opener.open('https://ethereumprice.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
div = soup.find('span', id='ep-price')
ethereum_rate = div.contents[0]

print ethereum_rate
```

Here's a simple and minimal example using FeedParser:

```
import feedparser

python_wiki_rss_url = "http://www.python.org/cgi-bin/moinmoin/" \
                       "RecentChanges?action=rss_rc"

feed = feedparser.parse( python_wiki_rss_url )

print feed
```